# Compare with datetime where the value must be greater than n minutes in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, robo3t

Record_collection as in database :

```
{
"_id": 792ydihd2989002,
"mydate":ISODate("2020-06-08T09:05:12.191Z"),

"_id": 7676wwhdhwte77,
"mydate":ISODate("2020-07-08T09:05:12.191Z"),

"_id": 7676wwhdeete77,
"mydate": ,

}
```

Expected Output:

I need a query to get all he records where the 'mydate' is older than 20 minutes or the mydate value is empty. Either the mydate must be 20 minutes older or null.

I have tried in pymongo also with mongodb but it matches with date and not with the time.

Comment: So are you asking how to build in ISODate for 20 minutes ago, or do you need to know how to query for a date range?

Comment: not date range, get records which are 20 minutes older@Joe

Comment: right, so in the date range from 20 minutes ago to the present

Comment: yes that is correct@Joe

Comment: So you get a current timestamp, subtract 20 minutes, and use that in the query.  There are already several questions on SO about querying a date range.  If you run into a specific problem, let us know.

Comment: Yes of course, like shall we move this to chat?@Joe